# ngx-material-timepicker: iPhone css ignores "position: fixed"

Tags: css, angular, position, mobile-safari

I created a StackBlitz to reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdzdxx

It has an ngx-material-timepicker with the following css:

```
.timepicker-backdrop-overlay[_ngcontent-c23] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    z-index: 999;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

In iPhone only, the css is locked inside the child-component.  In Android and desktop it works as expected.  Is there a known solution to this? [image]

Comment: error appears in safari desktop too

Comment: Safari seems to be inconsistent in applying z-index.  Is there a containing div for your overlay?   Try setting the z-index on it as well, as per the first answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071462/safari-ignores-z-index-value).  Another interesting discussion [here](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16341-zindex-and-safari-issue/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug reported for this issue here https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160953

It says,

> WebKit incorrectly clips position:fixed element, inside of its "position:relative; overflow: hidden" parent, IF that parent has "z-index" set

This is exactly what is happening here. The fixed positioned element with class `.timepicker-overlay` is placed inside the relatively positioned element `.mat-tab-body-active` which has a z-index of 1.

So what you can do for now is, override that style and set z-index for the active tab to `initial`.

```
.mat-tab-body.mat-tab-body-active {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: initial; // set z-index to inital
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

But If you change z-index of `.mat-tab-body.mat-tab-body-active` then `mat-tab-group` will not work as expected. Because as we change the z-index of active tab to initial it will go backward in the `mat-tab` stack. It's the default behavior of z-index. And you can only interact with the last tab.

To prevent that we can set pointer-events CSS property on `.mat-tab-body` as follows.

```
.mat-tab-body{
        pointer-events: none;
}
.mat-tab-body.mat-tab-body-active {
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        z-index: initial; 
        flex-grow: 1;
        pointer-events: all;
}
```

here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6a6gc3).

I have tested it on [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/), here is the screen-shot for same. *(this screen-shot is for the older answer)*
[image]

Comment: This appeared to work but broke the other material-tabs when leaving the tab.  Without the z-index I couldn't interact with any controls on the tabs.  I tried conditionally estting the z-index to initial only on one tab, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hi @MDave I have updated the answer. Actually there are several possible solution to overcome this z-index issue, but using pointer-events is the easiest and clean one. I am sure that this will work for you if it doesn't I will share other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

yes @dmcgrandle, it seems like z-index issues. But I find one patch with below code. add `'custom-tabbar'` on top of tabbar and override CSS like below.

```
.custom-tabbar .mat-tab-body-active {
  overflow: visible !important;
  position: static;
}
```

I didn't check in iPhone but I have a check in an emulator. Hope it's work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what fixed it for me.  I used it with ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-active.

Comment: After testing this for a while it wasn't reliable enough to use, for some reason sometimes it fixed it and sometimes it didn't.  Thanks anyway